# Is it possible to suspend rendering in tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, render

I have a GUI with a large number of widgets and each widget has a number of settings.  Plus, I have to make a number of calls to get all of the settings.  So, it takes a couple of seconds to set the GUI up.  As it is now, the GUI starts rendering while I am still setting it up.  It looks horrible and it slows down the completion of the final form.

Is there a way I can tell `tkinter` to stop rendering until the GUI is completely set up and then resume rendering?

I know it's possible to do this in WinForms.  In that case, I can just call `SuspendLayout()` to stop it from rendering while I'm changing it.  Does `tkinter` have a similar mechanism?

Edit ---

@martineau - Here is some test code to give you a better idea of what I am trying to do.

```
from array import *
from threading import Thread
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import time

arr=[]
isInit = False

def BuildGUI(value):
    """Draw out inital widgets """
    global isInit    
    rows, cols = (8, 8)
    root = Tk()
    for i in range(rows):
        col = []
        for j in range(cols):
            led = Label(root, text="",  bg="#000000", height = 2, width = 3)
            led.grid(row=j, column=i)
            col.append(led)
        arr.append(col)
    print(arr)
    isInit = True
    #wait for events
    root.mainloop()

class AnimTest:
    """ Animation Library"""
    def begin(self):
        if isInit == False:
            x = Thread(target=BuildGUI, args=(1,))
            x.daemon = True
            x.start()
            while isInit == False:
                print("initializing...")

    def clear(self):
        for x in range(0,8):
            for y in range(0,8):
                self.set_pixel(x, y, 0)
        #this happens at the start of drawing a new frame
        #i want to suspend rendering here

    def set_pixel(self, dispValY, dispValX, mode):
        pxl = arr[dispValX][dispValY] 
        if mode == 0: pxl.config(bg="#000000")
        else: pxl.config(bg="#00FF00")
        #this is used to draw out the fram

    def write_display(self):
        pass
        #i want everything to be rendered when 
        #this is called.

def runTest():
    anim = AnimTest()
    anim.begin()
    x = 0
    y = 2
    dx = dy = 1
    while True:
        x = x + dx
        if (x <= 0 or x >= 7): dx = -dx
        y = y + dy
        if (y <= 0 or y >= 7):dy = -dy
        anim.clear()
        anim.set_pixel(x,y,1)
        anim.write_display()
        time.sleep(1/60)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    runTest()
```

This test code should display an animation of a bouncing dot.  This particular animation doesn't look that bad.  But when I try to make more complex images, it looks very flashy.

I want it to suspend rendering when clear() is called and resume rendering when write_display() is called.

Comment: What if you call `root.withdraw()` just after you create your root and `root.deiconify()` after you are done setting it up? It will hide the window until the set up is done. In the mean time you can have a loading screen

Comment: Can you provide a [mre] that can be used as a test case?

Comment: I found a possible work-around to this particular problem.  I added a second 2d array called stateArray.  In clear(), I just set all of the elements in the stateArray to 0.  In set_pixel(), I set the selected element in the stateArray to 1.  Then, write_display() just transferrs all of the states from the stateArray to the corresponding elements in the UI array.  I would still like to know how to do a suspend layout in Tkinter though.

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter can't render anything until either `update` has been called, or `mainloop()` is running and allowed to continue. In other words, the default is to not render anything until the code which creates the UI has finished defining the UI.

If you find yourself in the situation where `update` is being called while you are in the process of defining the UI but you don't want the screen to be updated, the best solution is to either withdraw the window until it is ready, or add one frame between the window and all of the other widgets and then leave adding the frame to the window as your final step.